# Routing in razor pages core 2.2 with modelbinding incorrect model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want the `query` string to be converted to correct values, my `query` string looks like this, 
https://localhost:5001/Test?SampleId=14&Startdate=11%2F01%2F2020%2000%3A00%3A00&Enddate=11%2F29%2F2020%2000%3A00%3A00?culture=de

its `Datetime` values but if I clean a little.

https://localhost:5001/Test?SampleId=14&Startdate=2020-01-01&Enddate=2020-02-01?culture=de

My page model values :

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public String SampleId { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public DateTime Enddate { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var datestart = Startdate; // Correct value 
    var dateend = Enddate; // Value 2020-02-01?culture=de. I don't want ?culture=de
     ...
     ...
}
```

I also tried with :

```
@page "{SampleId:int}/{Startdate:datetime}/{Enddate:datetime}"
```

but it didn't work either.

Do I need some special `Property` to convert it correct?

I can strip with `string.Replace()` but it isn't nice!

Comment: I tested this and this query string works fine `https://localhost:5001/Test?SampleId=14&Startdate=2020-01-01&Enddate=2020-02-01`.  Notice the startDate and the replacement of `?culture=de`.  Having `?culture=de` throws off the Endate.

Comment: Have you try to route the parameters with the taghelper asp-route? Ex. asp-route-StartDate="@Model.StartDate" in your input and modify your Get method like OnGetAsync(string StartDate).

Answer (score 0):

Try the OnPageHandlerSelected method that executes before the model is selected. You can intercept the request, fix the query string and redirect.  I think you can probably come up with a better solution but this should put you in the right direction. Please see these resources for reference.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters

https://benjii.me/2017/04/parse-modify-query-strings-asp-net-core/

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;`
`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;`

```
public override void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        //...
        var querystring = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value);
        var items = querystring.SelectMany(x => x.Value, (col, value) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(col.Key, value)).ToList();
        var endDate = items.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "Enddate" && q.Value.Contains("?culture=de"));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate.Value))
        {
            items.Remove(endDate);
            var newEndDateValue = endDate.Value.Replace("?culture=de", "");
            var qb = new QueryBuilder(items);
            qb.Add("Enddate", newEndDateValue);

            Uri currentUrl = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl());
            var url = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", currentUrl.Scheme,Uri.SchemeDelimiter, currentUrl.Authority, currentUrl.AbsolutePath);
            Response.Redirect(url.ToString() + "?" + qb.ToQueryString());
        }

    }
```